# Which files do not need need to be added to source control for Sencha Touch app?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Which files do not need need to be added to source control for Sencha Touch app?
I've just added everything inside my app folder.
However I noticed there seems to be a lot going over the wire to the SVN repo.
In particular the /resources/css/sass/.sasscache folder. This doesn't sounds like something that should be in SVN.

Is there a definitive list anywhere which files should/shouldn't be checked in for a ST app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no "definitive" list, but you can definitely exclude any *.sasscache* folders, as well as */build/*. Most of the folders should be included in SVN.

If you're using Sencha Architect there might be other folders too.

Comment: Is there no definitive list then? I mean if I check-in everything I'm going to find files changing all over the place that might not need to be checked-in which is a bit annoying.